# Ubuntu 14.04 wired connection keep disconnecting

Tags: 14.04, ethernet, realtek

I was using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my Dell Vostro laptop. Yesterday I upgraded the same into Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, after upgrading my wired ethernet connection is getting automatically disconnected after connecting into wired net for 3 to 5 minutes, only unplugging and replugging ethernet cable reset the connection and I can access net (It showing it is "connected" in the network connection area, but i cant access internet till I unplug and reconnect it), the problem continue in every 3 to 5 minutes.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2`

```
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:065c]
Kernel driver in use: r8168
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 question edited with **lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2** output.

Comment: How did you install `r8168` driver?

Comment: @Pilot6 I didn't installed any driver manually, I think it get installed during upgrade.

Comment: That could not be the case. But anyway the issue is clear. If the answer solved the problem, please accept it by clicking the check sign at the left of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This adapter `[10ec:8168]` does not need `r8168` driver.

Default `r8169` module supports it better.

You can test it by

```
sudo modprobe -r r8168
sudo modprobe r8169
```

If you installed `r8168` from Ubuntu repositories, then run

```
sudo apt-get purge r8168-dkms
```

to make it permanent.