# Cannot connect to network after configuration changes (14.04 - RTL8111/8168/8411 ethernet controller)

Tags: 14.04, networking, ethernet, dkms

I am having trouble connecting to a wired network. This happened after some unintentional configuration changes. It's possible I may have accidentally uninstalled my networking driver. This computer has been working fine for roughly 2 years before these changes.

My ethernet hardware info (`lspci | grep Ethernet`):

`06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)`

I read online that this hardware frequently has issues. I read to install `r8168-dkms` driver, which might help solve my problem [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/933077). However, when I attempt to build the driver I get:

```
$ sudo dkms build r8168/8.037.00 -k $(uname -r)/$(uname -p)"
...
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.4.0-138-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-138-generic (x86_64)
```

At this point I'm not really sure what to try next. I don't have an internet connection, so I can't use `apt-get install` to install the drivers I need. Although, I am considering going and buying a cheap USB ethernet connection to help me.

**How I got in this situation**

The problem began after I installed snap: `sudo apt-get install snapd`

After installation the system was still working, but next time I restarted my the computer the screen was low-res and going through a login loop. Looking at some error logs, I found this to be an issue with nvidia drivers.

I uninstalled snap, and the nvidia drivers. I was able to login, but found I was now unable to connect to my wired network. It's possible I accidentally uninstalled more than just the nvidia drivers (ie. accidentally uninstalled a chipset driver). Another possibility is that the installation of snap affected the networking drivers similar to how it affected the nvidia drivers.

**EDIT 1**

I downloaded the .deb for `r8168/8.041.00` and successfully built it. I got the .deb from [here](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/r8168).

When I tried to run `sudo dkms build ...` for the driver, I get:

`Module r8168/8.04.00 already built for kernel 4.4.0-138-generic/4`

However, my networking problems are not fixed. I no longer see `eth0` in `ifconfig`. I might try one of the newer .deb and see if that fixes.

**EDIT 2**

I got a USB ethernet card which allowed me to connect to the internet. I turned my focus to installing the nvidia drivers. That is what's now giving me problems. No matter what driver I install, I get the login loop. At this point I'm considering buying a new GPU and/or upgrading to 16.06...

Comment: Please focus on one problem at a time. But yes, you should **install 16.04 or 18.04 from scratch** - 14.04 has only a few months left of support. Do NOT try to upgrade an already broken system.

Comment: Hmm, my GPU is also 10 years old and no longer supported. Time to update I guess